# Where in ViewController should my date picker initialization go?

Tags: ios, swift

Given my code below, where should I place this in ViewController? 
I tried placing it inside viewWillAppear() but I am not seeing the effects when I run my app.

```
// Set birthday date picker min and max
        let currentDate: NSDate = NSDate()
        let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
        calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")!
        let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
        components.calendar = calendar
        components.year = -18
        let minDate: NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
        components.year = -150
        let maxDate: NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
        self.birthdayDatePicker.minimumDate = minDate
        self.birthdayDatePicker.maximumDate = maxDate
```

Comment: You could put this code in `viewDidLoad` or any method called after that like `viewWillAppear`. I think `minDate` and `maxDate` are backwards since `maxDate` will come before `minDate`.